# Commodore 1352 mouse converter

Tags: commodore, 80286, mouse

My Commodore PC30-III can only handle a Commodore 1352 mouse, but it is practically impossible to buy one. I own a couple of Amiga and serial PC mice that if I plug in, the buttons seem to work, but not the cursor movement.

I am wondering if it would be possible to build a converter. According to the [service manaual](https://www.retro-commodore.eu/download.php?file=Commodore_PC30-III_Service_Manual_pn314118-01.pdf)'s page 33 the port has the following layout:

[image: Pinout diagram]

Comment: A converter to what?

Comment: @user3840170 Obviously, a converter that allows connecting some type of mouse available for buying today to the computer.

Answer (score 2):

> I own a couple of amiga

- The Amiga mouse should work, as both are proporional mice using the same interface/pinout (see [here](https://old.pinouts.ru/InputCables/AmigaMouseJoy_pinout.shtml)).
- An [Atari ST compatible](https://old.pinouts.ru/InputCables/atari_st_joystick_pinout.shtml) mouse might need switching of some lines to work (IIRC flipping pin 2/3).
- Same goes got an Amstrad PC1512 mouse (see section 1.16 of t[his page](https://www.seasip.info/AmstradXT/1512tech/section1.html))

All of them are proportional mice, that is they use a joystick like interface encoding movement as a series of phased pulses.

> and serial PC mouse

Well, a serial (like a USB) won't work, as it's a different interface. For anything but proportional C64/Amiga/Atari mice you'll need a converter. By now there are many different to be used.

Examples (not recommendations) are:

- For USB the [mouSTer](https://www.hackster.io/news/mouster-is-a-universal-usb-mouse-adapter-for-retro-computers-6e6f8dd07e1d) should work fine with the PC-30/III
- For PS/2 the [Mouse Converter](https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/ATARI_ST_PS_2_MOUSE_CONVERTER__ADAPTER____PIC16F628_A_.html)
  Or, if you try to learn the basics, look at [this page](http://sensi.org/%7Esvo/%5Bm%5Douse/)

As said, these are usually switchable (by soldering or programming) between different formats, so Amiga setting will do it for the PC-30/III. There are many converter solutions out there,so pick your favourite.

Comment: According to [this site](https://www.c64-wiki.de/wiki/Mouse_1351), the 1351 is not compatible to the Amiga: It has two operating modes: In one mode, it simulates a digital joystick when the mouse is moved (e.g. pressing the stick up is simulated when moving the mouse upwards). In the other operating mode, the 1351 outputs two analogue signals. However, the 1352 outputs a quadrature signal.

Comment: Now that's kinda interesting. Deleting that part, since I do not have a 1531 at hand to check. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all the information, but I am not sure how is it related to a commodore PC-30 and a 1352 mouse.

Comment: @PeterSzanto The 1532 is of the same type of mouse as the Amiga, Atari ST or Amstrad PC1512 mouse. So either of them will work. That's what the interface you posted tells as well. Serial, PS/2 or USB mice will not work, as they use different transmission. They will need some adaptor/converter to convert their data packets into the right number of pulse signals for the PC-30.

Comment: @Raffzahn so is there any logical reason why an amiga mouse doesn't work? I tried two amiga mouses, they both work with an amiga and but only the buttons work with the PC

Comment: @PeterSzanto No, not really. Which might bring up the next question: Do you have a mouse that works with the PC? After all, beside the mouse being incompatible, there's always the posibility of the interface being damaged and or driver issues.

Comment: @Raffzahn I don't have a mouse that works with this machine, that is the problem... I was suspecting a port failure, but when I connected a QuickShot joystick it was able to move the cursor in 3 of the 8 possible directions, so I suspect the port is ok and the machine really needs a mouse different then the standard amiga mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a [useful website](http://ode2commies.blogspot.com/2020/01/attack-of-mouse-clones.html) that explains the differences between the different CBM tank mice. The author says at the end:

> The 1352 and the Amiga Tank Mouse are the exact same mouse. The only difference is the box they came in.

So I believe your dedicated Amiga mice *should* work on a Commodore PC30-III. Maybe it's a driver issue? (I can see [you've asked that already](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/21836/commodore-mouse-not-recognized-by-a-commodore-pc30-iii-286-machine) though)

Thanks Bruce Abbott in the comments noting that the 1352 packaging explicitly says it's a PC-III and Amiga 500 compatible mouse.

[image]

Comment: This was in response to a comment left by someone whose name sounds strangely familiar. (Still, it may be of use to future readers at least to repeat it here.)

Comment: Yes I asked about the driver question separately, but my conclusion is that it isn't a driver questions. The Commodore PC III's operating manual says that only the 1352 mouse should work, not an amiga tank mouse.

Comment: https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41EQZFjuK6L._AC_.jpg